# Underscore.js, remove duplicates in array of objects based on key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates, underscore.js

I have the following JS array:

```
var myArray = [{name:"Bob",b:"text2",c:true},
               {name:"Tom",b:"text2",c:true},
               {name:"Adam",b:"text2",c:true},
               {name:"Tom",b:"text2",c:true},
               {name:"Bob",b:"text2",c:true}
               ];
```

I want to eliminate the indexes with name value duplicates and recreate a new array, with distinct names, eg:

```
var mySubArray = [{name:"Bob",b:"text2",c:true},
                  {name:"Tom",b:"text2",c:true},
                  {name:"Adam",b:"text2",c:true},
                 ];
```

As you can see, I removed "Bob" and "Tom", leaving only 3 distinct names. Is this possible with Underscore? How?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this use case demands more than just _.filter

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: I tried _.filter but maybe I couldn't find a way to use it properly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With **Underscore**, use [`_.uniq`](https://underscorejs.org/#uniq) with a custom transformation, a function like [`_.property('name')`](https://underscorejs.org/#property) would do nicely or just `'name'`, as @Gruff Bunny noted in the comments :

```
var mySubArray = _.uniq(myArray, 'name');
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/02ugrbzr/

If you use **Lodash** and not Underscore, go with the example given by @Jacob van Lingen in the comments and use [_.uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniqBy):

```
var mySubArray = _.uniqBy(myArray, 'name')
```

Comment: You could just pass 'name' as the third parameter to _.uniq

Comment: and remove the second parameter leaving just _.uniq(myArray, 'name') - just peeked at the underscore source

Comment: Note for lodash, it is: `_.uniqBy(myArray, 'name')`

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is definitely best but here's another that's not much longer that also exposes you to more underscore method's, if you're interested in learning:

```
var mySubArray = []

_.each(_.uniq(_.pluck(myArray, 'name')), function(name) {
    mySubArray.push(_.findWhere(myArray, {name: name}));
})
```