# Get get unique ObjectID's from an array containing duplicates

Tags: javascript, mongoose

So I have an array of ObjectID's, for example:

```
console.log(objectIdArray);
```

gives `[ObjectID, ObjectID, ObjectID]`.

However there are duplicates here, as seen when mapping to ID strings:

```
var idArray = objectIdArray.map(objectId => objectId.toString());
console.log(idArray);
```

gives `["5afa54e5516c5b57c0d43227", "5afa54e5516c5b57c0d43227", "5afa54f0516c5b57c0d43228"]` where you can see the ID ending in **27** is duplicated twice.

How can I filter this array of ObjectID's to remove the duplicates (keeping the complete **ObjectID** objects, not just the ID string values)?

Comment: I often add the values of the array to a map ( `var map = {}; array.forEach(id => map[id] = true // or original object)` ) and then return `Object.keys(map)` or `Object.values(map)`. O(n) time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const removeDuplicates = inputArray => {
    const ids = [];
    return inputArray.reduce((sum, element) => {
       if(!ids.includes(element.toString()){
           sum.push(element);
           ids.push(element.toString());
       }
       return sum;
    }, []);
};
```

This solution will remove all the objects that aren't the first object with a certain Id.

We fill an `Array` with the ids, then we check if the ids already are filled in the current list.

---

The above solution can be potentially slow if there is a lot of elements since you need to check the list of ids which is *O(n)* for each iteration in the `inputArray` which would put the algorithm at *O(n^2)+O(n)*

So instead, we can sort it first based on `toString()` then we can just verify that the current id didn't match the last id we saw.

```
const removeDuplicates = inputArray => {
    const sortedArray = inputArray.sort((a,b) => (a.toString() > b.toString() ? 1 : (a.toString() < b.toString() ? -1 : 0)));

    let lastSeen = undefined;
    return sortedArray.reduce((sum, element) => {
       if(lastSeen !== element.toString()){
           sum.push(element);
       }
       lastSeen = element.toString();
       return sum;
    }, []);
};
```

Now the algorithm is *O(n log n) + O(n)* assuming sort uses [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ES6 you can take Sajeetharan's answer, but create a set of objects, not their ids:

```
let nodupes = [...new Set(objectIdArray)];
```

Comment: They work on everything: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: I don't believe JavaScript Set's work with full objects, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404607/why-does-javascript-set-not-do-unique-objects). Doing what you mention above doesn't remove any ObjectID's.

Comment: That's because objects are not compared by their contents, they must be references to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline to prevent the situation of having a final result with duplicate ObjectId values.

However:

```
// Define callback Function to receive modified Array
var receiveModifiedArray = function(objectIdArray) {
    // log modified Array to console
    console.log(objectIdArray);
}

// Remove duplicate ObjectId values
function removeDuplicateObjectIdValues(objectIdArray, callback) {

    // Iterate through each ObjectId
    objectIdArray.forEach((currentValue, index, array) => {
        // evaluate Array items with index greater than 0
        if(index > 0) {

            // check ObjectId string values for type and value equality
            if(currentValue.toString() == array[index -1].toString()) {
                /**
                 * The splice() method changes the contents of an array
                 * by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.
                 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
                 */
                objectIdArray.splice(index,1);
            }

            // If processing last item in Array, callback
            if(index == array.length +1) {
                callback(objectIdArray);
            }
        }
    });

    // Return to move on to next message in call stack
    return;
}

// Remove duplicate ObjectId values
removeDuplicateObjectIdValues(objectIdArray,receiveModifiedArray);
```